# Add multiple icons and space in Font Awesome with css content

Tags: css, font-awesome

I can use Font Awesome icons in the following way:

```
.icon-car {
  content: "\f1b9";
}
```

Is it possible to make it to contain more than one icon (say `\f1b9` and `\f1b8`), with a non-breaking space in between once?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can either use non-break unicode character `\00a0`.

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");

.icon-demo:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: "\f1b9\00a0\00a0\00a0\f1b8";
}
```

```html
<span class="icon-demo"></span>
```

Or, simply use one blank space  in between, in most of the case, however if you need more than one space, make sure to set `white-space: pre;`, so that any whitespace will be preserved.

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");

.icon-demo:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: "\f1b9          \f1b8";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<span class="icon-demo"></span>
```